# Check, if list is a sublist of another list

Tags: haskell

I'd like to write a function that checks if one list is a sublist of another list. I wrote this, but it is not working, but I need something like this, I guess. Thanks for help.

```
subList :: Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> Bool
subList _ []    = False
subList [] _    = True
subList (x:xs) (y:ys) =   
     x == y    = subList xs ys   
     otherwise = subList (x:xs) ys
```

Comment: Be more specific about how it is not working.  Is it an error?  Is it giving the wrong output?

Comment: Your first case precludes the empty list from being a sublist of the empty list.

Comment: Define "sublist". Your attempt implies you want `[1,3]` to be a sublist of `[1,2,3]`, but one could imagine that `x` is a sublist of `y` iff there are (possibly empty) lists `w` and `z` such that `w ++ x ++ z == y`.

Comment: Looks like you're trying to use Pattern Guards in the last 3 lines, but don't quite have the syntax correct.  Delete the `=` from the first of those 3 lines, and add `|` (guard) character to the beginning of the remaining 2 lines.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code is close to working, but just needs some minor changes. As other have said in the comments, you need to include `|` pattern guards, and remove `=` from the first function call. Here is what the last 3 lines should look like:

```
subList (x:xs) (y:ys)   
    | x == y    = subList xs ys   
    | otherwise = subList (x:xs) ys
```

This will fix up your code for the most part, but you also need to add the base case `subList [] [] = True`, because the empty list `[]` is the a sublist of another empty list `[]`, just like `[1]` is a sublist of `[1]`.

Adding these changes, your code would look like this:

```
subList :: Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> Bool
subList [] [] = True
subList _ []    = False
subList [] _    = True
subList (x:xs) (y:ys) 
    | x == y    = subList xs ys   
    | otherwise = subList (x:xs) ys
```

Some example calls:

```
Prelude> subList [] []
True
Prelude> subList [1] [1,2,3]
True
Prelude> subList [1] [4,2,3]
False
Prelude> subList [1] []
False
Prelude> subList [1,2] [1,2]
True
Prelude> subList [1,2] [2,1]
False
Prelude> subList [1,2] [1,2,2,1]
True
```

However, their is problem with a call like this:

```
Prelude> subList [1,3] [1,2,3]
True
```

implying that `[1,3]` is a sublist of `[1,2,3]`. This could be intended, but if it is not, then you need to change your approach.

**Another approach:**

For your two lists, `xs` and `ys`, You could instead split the `ys` into sublists of length `xs`, let's say `subys`, and check if `xs` exists in `subys`. To do this, you could use [`splitAt`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:splitAt), which splits a list every `n` characters. Here is an example function:

```
split_lists :: Int -> [a] -> [[a]]
split_lists _ [] = []
split_lists n xs
    | length first == n = first : restxs
    | otherwise = restxs
    where (first, rest) = splitAt n xs
          restxs = split_lists n (tail first ++ rest)
```

If you don't wish to use `splitAt`, you could do something like this:

```
split_lists :: Int -> [a] -> [[a]]
split_lists _ [] = []
split_lists n xs = filter (\x -> length x == n) list
    where list = take n xs : split_lists n (drop 1 xs)
```

Which behaves like:

```
Prelude> split_lists 3 [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
[[1,2,3],[2,3,4],[3,4,5],[4,5,6],[5,6,7],[6,7,8],[7,8,9],[8,9,10]]
```

Then you could just use [`any`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:any) to check if the first list exists in the second list splitted into sublists, or you could just use normal recursion, up to you.

Here is an example using `any`:

```
subList :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [a] -> Bool
subList [] [] = True
subList xs ys = any (==xs) subys
    where subys = (split_lists (length xs) ys)
```

Here is an example using recursion:

```
subList :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [a] -> Bool
subList [] [] = True
subList xs ys = check_lists xs subys
    where subys = (split_lists (length xs) ys)

check_lists :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [[a]] -> Bool
check_lists _ [] = False
check_lists xs (y:ys)
    | xs == y = True
    | otherwise = check_lists xs ys
```

Which now behaves as follows:

```
Prelude> subList [] []
True
Prelude> subList [1] [1,2,3]
True
Prelude> subList [1] [4,2,3]
False
Prelude> subList [1] []
False
Prelude> subList [1,2] [1,2]
True
Prelude> subList [1,2] [2,1]
False
Prelude> subList [1,2] [1,2,2,1]
True
Prelude> subList [1,3] [1,2,3]
False
Prelude> subList [1,2] [0,1,2,3]
True
```

Comment: is this tail or forward recursive?

Answer (score 6):

You could use the function intersect like this:

intersect [list1] [list2] == [list1]

```
*Test> intersect [] [] == []
True
*Test> intersect [1] [] == [1]
False
*Test> intersect [2,4,6,4] [9,5,4,2,6,3,3] == [2,4,6,4]
True
*Test> intersect [1,2,3] [3,2,5,4] == [1,2,3]
False
```

You will have to import Data.List for this.