# Check if all elements from first argument appears in the second argument

Tags: haskell

I get the wrong result from my code.

I want to check if the elements from the first argument list appears in the second argument list, and I used the code from this quiestion [Check, if list is a sublist of another list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47232335/check-if-list-is-a-sublist-of-another-list) but i don't get the desired result.

```hs
del :: Eq t => [t] -> [t] -> Bool
del [] [] = True 
del _ []  = False 
del [] _  = True
del (x:xs) (y:ys)
    | x == y    = del xs ys
    | otherwise = del (x:xs) ys
```

```
del [2,3] [3,3,1]  -- should return False, which it does, but 
del "cbbbc" "bca"  -- should return True, but instead it returns False
```

and I don't understand why?

Comment: May I congratulate you for an excellently written question, well done!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`"cbbbc"` is not a sublist of `"bca"`, meaning the list `"cbbbc"` doesn't appear inside `"bca"`, like, for instance, `"ca"` does. Your problem is a different one. Here's a working code, in O(n) time complexity:

```hs
del :: Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> Bool
del xs ys = all (`elem` ys) xs
```

It means: return `True` if (and only if), for every `x` in `xs`, `x` is element of `ys`.

Answer (score 2):

You are removing `y` too soon; just because `x /= y` doesn't mean `x == z` won't be true for some other value `z` in `ys`. This is much easier to implement (with `elem`) if you don't need to remove `y` at *all*. If you do, you'll have to do a little more work to remove the correct element from `ys` when you do find a match. (For instance, should `del [1, 1] [1]` return True, or False because `1` doesn't appear twice in the second list?)

Comment: Directly translated i'm trying to "check if each element that occurs in the first list, also occurs in the second list", the way i understand it del [1,1] [1] should return True.

Comment: Ok, then `elem` (or your own implementation of it) is the way to go. The other answer provides one possible solution.