# How to filter a list of lists using a list in haskell

Tags: list, haskell

I have this list of lists

```
a = [["a","b","c"],["d","e","f"]]
b = ["a","b"]
```

I want to filter a using b

so the output should be
`["a","b","c"]`

all elements in b should be in a

Comment: This is really ambiguous. Do all of the elements in `b` have to be in the lists in `a`, or just one? Also, do they need to be exact or is an infix match good enough?

Comment: yes all of the elements in b should be in a, and infix match is good enough, can you please help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to get all elements in `a` that have all of the elements in `b`. If you want the elements in `b` to absolutely be contiguous in `a`, this will to the trick:

```
import Data.List
f :: Eq a => [a] -> [[a]] -> [[a]]
f b a = filter (b `isSubsequenceOf`) a
```

If, by "infix match", you meant that your filtering condition was for `b` to be an infix of an element in `a` (and not a prefix or a suffix), then you can use `isInfixOf`, from `Data.List`, instead on `isSubsequenceOf` in the example above.

If you want to allow matches where elements are not contiguous (this isn't clear in your question), then you can do this:

```
f :: Eq a => [a] -> [[a]] -> [[a]]
f b a = filter (\el -> el `intersect` b == b) a
--or, in pointfree form
f b a = filter ((b ==) . (`intersect` b)) a
```

[Credit where credit is due](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60238887/7096763) for this last piece of code.

Note that these functions will return all possible matches (`[[a]]`); if instead you only want the first match, simply pattern match to extract the first element or headMay from package `safe`:

```
fOnly1 b a = case f b a of
  (x:_) -> Just x
  _     -> Nothing

fOnly1' b a = headMay $ f b a
```